# What could cause a 301 redirection? I can't find the source of one

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website hosted at Ionos, I built a website using Wordpress and Avada on a temporary domain provided by Ionos (`https://my-site.live-website.com` or something like that). Everything was fine on the live-website domain, so I decided to have the final domain name point to the final website. I changed the domain name in the Wordpress settings and used the dedicated automated tool on Ionos to change the DNS table of the final domain. After a few minutes, I tried the final domain; but noticed there was a redirect: whenever I put `https://my-site.com` in the address bar, I get a 301 redirection to `https://my-site.com/cms` (I know it's 301 because I used a plugin for Google Chrome). This is a problem as `/cms` does not exist on this Wordpress website.

I set up the website's home page through the Avada appearance options, and the permalink on that page is the root of the domain: `https://my-site.com.` So everything seems OK on the side of Wordpress.

Then, I thought it may be a problem with the automatic DNS config, so I looked up the DNS table, and it seems fine, especially as no other page has this problem.

I thought it may be a problem with the `.htaccess` and `wp-config.php`, but there was no identifiable redirection in them (and there was no problem on the live website. So I can't imagine how it could have appeared suddenly).

I called Ionos a few times for that problem. On my first call, they put me on hold for ~10 minutes and came back telling me: "There is a problem with your database due to one of your plugin or theme updates, either you find it yourself or you can pay us to intervene as it requires 'codating' *(sic, 'du codage' in the original conversation in French)*".

I then looked up the database through phpMyAdmin and found no occurrence of "/cms". I found two occurrences of "cms", but inside longtext variables, so nothing that could have an impact on redirections as far as I know. Also, these two occurrences were part of a longer URL not related to the website (e.g. `https://external-site.com/cms/pages/4231`) so very unlikely to be the cause of my problem.

As I was in kind of a hurry (the website being that of my fiancée's clients who needs it for business) and having little time, I asked Ionos to intervene on what they perceived in the database, and they said they "made a note" and would charge the client (which means we will have to refund them).

Since then, nothing has been done yet. The website still points to a 404 page. So I called Ionos to have an update on the situation. The person on the phone with me took a very long time to investigate the problem himself (big thanks for that). He looked up the `.htaccess`, DNS table, database, `wp-config.php` and drew the same conclusions I had drawn. He asked me to deactivate my theme and plugins (which are very few) to see if it solved anything: of course not!

In the end, after a 42' long call, he said he was at his wits' end and had no clue where it could come from, but said Wordpress was probably at fault for the redirection, which seems weird to me as, again, there was no problem on the live website. He also said the admins would not work on it until (at best) tomorrow. So I am posting this message because the client is (understandably) unhappy with the situation and pressuring us to solve the problem ASAP.

So the question is: is there anywhere I forgot to look up for a 301 redirection?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about WordPress development and administration can be asked on [wordpress.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Comment: Ionos appear to have done far more than they should. As I understand it they are a host, not a software engineering firm. Their job is to keep the servers running, the code is the customer's problem. So I wonder if you should find a WordPress developer and get them to set it up (and debug it) locally.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all DNS records are sorted.

I recommend you to go through the following checklist, even if you felt you checked before, do it again.

95% of the time it's one of these.

1. Go to database (via phpMyAdmin) and check `wp_options` table, look for `siteurl` and `home` option names (also note: they should not end with /).
2. Go to FTP, wp-content/plugins folder if you see any redirect plugin there, rename it's folder by adding or removing letter, this will deactivate it.
3. If you can see backend but not front end, try re-saving permalink structure and flush cache plugin if installed. (and consider running plugin like search-replace to get rid of all old links)
4. Finally - Chrome/chromium loves to cache url/redirects, all above might be already sorted.. so use incognito/private tab to see if that's the case. If that was the culprit - tell your client to restart PC, it usually clears url cache.

Best of luck

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help... I took the steps you mentioned, however, none of the above worked for me.